# Where can I get Centos 6.5?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I am deploying a product for my department which calls for CentOS 6.5. When I browse the CentOS downloads, I am only seeing 6.6 available with no means of finding 6.5. Our vendors have only stated support for 6.5, though I imagine there are significant security fixes in 6.6.

Where can I find an image for Centos 6.5?

Comment: I would doubt they won't support CentOS 6.6, and as such I would try and install it on CentOS 6.6 and see if it really doesn't work. Chances are high it will work. They probably won't support CentOS 6.4 and lower though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal address is http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6.5/isos/ but the CentOS project is no longer hosting any direct downloads for it (it's expensive!); you will have to use a mirror.

When you go to the above url, you will have to choose between a folder for x86 (i386), and a folder for x86-64, when you click into that folder you will be re-directed to a small list of third party mirrors. Unfortunately the redirect page is for 6.6, but the mirrors do have 6.5 isos, including the one @jjlin suggests. You just have to browse through the parent directories to find it. Eg: http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/centos/6.5/isos/

Answer (score 3):

In a mirror URL, just replace `6.6` with `6.5`. E.g.,

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.6/isos/x86_64/
```

becomes

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6.5/isos/x86_64/
```

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, look in http://vault.centos.org where CentOS archives its stale minor releases.